# Replicate SQL Server table using ActiveMQ

Tags: apache, sql-server-2008, jms, activemq-classic

I hope you can help me with this:

I have two database tables in separate servers, and I want them to be synchronized, I mean that when one of them is modified (Insert, delete, update), the other one is modified too. I´ve been searching for a while now and I´ve found that this can be acomplished with ActiveMQ, but, I haven´t found the way of doing It, can anybody give me a clue or a tutorial or something?.
I really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want to mix in ActiveMQ for the task?
ActiveMQ is a message broker to send event messages around. There is no out-of-the-box database synchronization of DB events with ActiveMQ. You probably have to use Apache Camel (or custom code) to read and write the databases. That would be a non trivial task, non the less, since there are things as transactions, table locks you need to take into account.

If replication is all that is needed for HA or backup, you should really look at the [built in mechanisms of SQL server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
What I would really like is to read all the  messages from activeMQ an insert them into two databases, can that be done with  camel?, do you have a tutorial or something like that?.
Thanks in advance.